# How to call PHP page through ajax call on java page

Tags: java, php

I have java URL which includes php page header .Now on header there is button which calls javascript function which eventually calls php file (ajax call)
the url is like this

```
http://localhost:8080/project/welcome.htm
```

header is header.php 
body is javas body and again 
footer is php footer.

How can I call my php page.

Please suggest

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jquery. It is the easy one

Include jquery through following link

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

and call following function in Javascript

```
$.ajax({
url: "header.php",
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

in .done function, you can do anything you want to do after calling your PHP file

Comment: what about sending parameter? like uid

Comment: nope its hitting url correctly but in firebug its showing url in red mark

Comment: Any error you got in firebug ? If it is hitting the url correctly, are you able to get your provided parameters in php file ?